# CSS file not updating when using GulpJS with Browser sync

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-cache, gulp-watch

I'm using GulpJS as a build tool to concat and minify my styles into 1 script. I'm watching my css files for changes and then doing the necessary performance things in a css gulp task before reloading the page with browser sync. For some reason the browser reloads and the css changes are not applied. If i attempt to put a `background: red` on `body` to test, no change occurs. If I then go in to the new `styles.css` file I see that the css task does its job of combining the files (including the change) and pushing it to 1 unified file, but that file is not used. After a few hours of researching I think it may have to do with Chrome caching the old css file? Here's the relevant part of my `gulpfile.js`:

```
// css task 
gulp.task('css:dev', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/assets/css/src/*.css')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
            .pipe(prefix({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            }))
            .pipe(cssNano())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});


// watch for file and changes and reload browser
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/assets/css/src/*.css', ['css:dev']);
});
```

I'm also noticing the output in my terminal when the `css:dev` task runs:

`GET /assets/css/styles.css?v=2388785908 200 21.388 ms - -`

`styles.css?=#############` seems like an older version?? I'm a little lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you inserting the css in your html?

Comment: @vivekVDwivedi `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css"}}" />`

Comment: so are you getting styles.css in your assets.css folder or some versioned file? Instead of loading the file manually, you can actually try injecting the files using gulp and wiredep. I believe you are getting a versioned file, if not, get one to avoid browser caching.

Comment: I'm getting a versioned file. When my gulp tasks run, the output in my terminal shows that it is GETTING a versioned `styles.css`:

`GET /assets/css/styles.css?v=2388785908 200 21.388 ms - -`

Changing any css file in the `src` folder triggers `gulp watch` which in turn triggers `css:dev` to do its thing on the css files, merge / min / push to `assets/css`, etc. I can confirm that the `styles.css` file is updated in `assets/css`, but my browser reloads and does not reload with this updated stylesheet. Instead it is reloading with an old version

Comment: Are you piping the `browserSync.stream()` method after the build is done? Since I don't have all your code, it's hard to debug what's wrong. I would suggest starting with a simple gulp build that will just load css file from a directory. Change the version manually and check if the new file is loaded or not. Once that task is correct, you already have rest of the tasks.

Comment: Your css link call in the html is to an unversioned assets/css/styles.css?